# Read list from csv, len only shows one item

Tags: python, csv

Here is the only row in the csv file:

```
0.0028,0.008,0.0014,0.008,0.0014,0.008,0.0014,0.008,0.0014,0.008,0.0028,0.0
```

I want to read it into a list and count the number of items.

```
import csv
with open('StackupThick.csv', 'r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=',')
    mylist = list(reader)
    print(mylist)
    print(len(mylist))
```

But, the printout looks like this:

```
[['0.0028', '0.008', '0.0014', '0.008', '0.0014', '0.008', '0.0014', '0.008', '0.0014', '0.008', '0.0028', '0.0']]
1
```

What bothers me is that the double brackets, and that the len returns just one.
Shouldn't it have just one bracket instead of two; and shouldn't the len return 12?

Comment: well, try to duplicate your row in CSV and think about how this should be represented: as `list` of records or a single record

Comment: as @AzatIbrakov said, this is teh intended behavious. `reader` expects a file full of csvs, not a single line, so each line is its own item. yes it feels silly when you only have a single line

Comment: "Shouldn't it have just one bracket instead of two" - thinking in terms of the number of brackets won't help in this case. You should understand what these two brackets _mean_ first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go through the rows of the file:

```
import csv
with open('StackupThick.csv', 'r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
        print(len(row))
```

Which gives:

```
['0.0028', '0.008', '0.0014', '0.008', '0.0014', '0.008', '0.0014', '0.008', '0.0014', '0.008', '0.0028', '0.0']
12
```

Have a look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader).

Comment: This works after I added parenthesis around the print objects. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I was using Python 2

Comment: Now I want to create a unique variable for each item in list (it would be best if the variable name ended with the item number in the list, like variable0 = (row[0]). Can this be done with a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

csv.reader returns an object that allows iteration over the *rows* of your CSV. Your file has 1 row. If you want to iterate over the columns within a row, you can do:

```
reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=',')
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```